# Parse Query - unable to retrieve an objects

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to execute a simple query to parse in order to retrieve some rows from the table.
My app contains two different screens. when i'm running the code below, in the "onCreate" method in the first and the main screen, everything works fine. the problem is that I want to execute my queries and deal with the object in the second screen or even in new class that will deal with parse connections.

when I was trying to run it in the "onCreate" method in the second screen or in different class,I couldn't reach to the code block inside "findInBackground" method therefore nothing was happened.

What am I missing? why this code block is running perfectly in the main screen but not in other screens as well. (I did initialize the connection in the second screen also)

the code is

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Main");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
               if (e == null) {

                     //some code is written here
               }

               else {
                    //some code is written here

                 }

        }
     });
```

thanks!

Comment: did you check to see if your else clause is being executed?

Comment: yes i checked, its not. when I debugged it, i noticed that it comes to this line "query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {"
without going inside the block.